# How to find out the amount of selected checkboxes/items in ListView (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listview, checkbox

Is there anyone who knows how can I find out the number of selected items in a ListView with checkboxes especially in VBA?

My approach is as follows. When I click on a Checkbox in this ListView then the application have to check if the selected items are more than three then throw an error message.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    If checked items > 3 then
         //Error message
    Else
         //continues
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the [list items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443480(v=vs.60).aspx) and query the [Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
' Returns the number of selected items.
Dim li As ListItem  ' Used to loop over all items.
Dim c As Integer    ' Used to count selected items.

    ' Loop over each item.
    For Each li In ListView1.ListItems

        ' Increase count if selected.
        If li.Checked = True Then c = c + 1
    Next

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox c, vbInformation, "Selected Items"
End Sub
```

**Edit**

The Checked property only works if your listbox uses checkboxes.  In all other cases use the selected property.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This property is useful only if the CheckBoxes property of the
>   ListView control the item is contained in is set to true. You can use
>   this property to determine if the item has been checked by the user or
>   through code at run time. To determine all the items that are checked
>   in a ListView control, you can use the CheckedItems property. To take
>   action when an item has been checked, you can create an event handler
>   for the ItemCheck property of the ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the SelectedItems property?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: in VBA you don't have `.SelectedItems`